# Can't create table in Oracle using tera term

Tags: sql, database, oracle

This is my text file which I am executing in tera term.

```
DROP TABLE purchase; CREATE TABLE purchase            
( ID  NUMBER(4) NOT NULL, 
               Fname VARCHAR2(10), 
               Lname VARCHAR2(10),
               Vin NUMBER(10),
               Email VARCHAR(10), 
               unit NUMBER(10), 
               Street VARCHAR2(50), 
               Suburb VARCHAR2(50), 
               Pcode NUMBER(4),
               credit VARCHAR2(20),
               holder VARCHAR2(20),
               Expiry NUMBER(4)
               Primary key (ID) 
             );    commit;
```

I'm getting the error

```
DROP TABLE purchase
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

       Primary key (ID)
                   *
ERROR at line 14:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Comment: The Oracle documentation is comprehensive and online.  You should learn to use it.  Find the CREATE TABLE documentation here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7002.htm#i2153108  If you had compared the given example with  your code you would have solved this for yourself, which is definitely the most rewarding way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
DROP TABLE purchase;
CREATE TABLE purchase            
         ( ID  NUMBER(4) NOT NULL, 
           Fname VARCHAR2(10), 
           Lname VARCHAR2(10),
           Vin NUMBER(10),
           Email VARCHAR(10), 
           unit NUMBER(10), 
           Street VARCHAR2(50), 
           Suburb VARCHAR2(50), 
           Pcode NUMBER(4),
           credit VARCHAR2(20),
           holder VARCHAR2(20),
           Expiry NUMBER(4),
           CONSTRAINT purchase_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID) 
         );
```

*BEWARE* the first error (ORA-00942) about `purchase` not existing is no problem... this happens when you run this the first time.

Answer (score 0):

or this:

```
DROP TABLE purchase;
CREATE TABLE purchase            
         ( ID  NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY, 
           Fname VARCHAR2(10), 
           Lname VARCHAR2(10),
           Vin NUMBER(10),
           Email VARCHAR(10), 
           unit NUMBER(10), 
           Street VARCHAR2(50), 
           Suburb VARCHAR2(50), 
           Pcode NUMBER(4),
           credit VARCHAR2(20),
           holder VARCHAR2(20),
           Expiry NUMBER(4)
         );
```

applying a primary key constraint to a column implies both "unique" and "not null" constraint(s).